# Postfix: Users impersonating other users at same domain

Tags: postfix

I've a postfix email server running and everything was fine... well until someone decided to impersonate other users. The current situation is:

- `user1@mydomain.dev` can send email with a faked `from` header saying it is `user2@mydomain.dev`;

At the faked emails headers I can see this:

`From: User2 <user2@mydomain.dev>`

`(Authenticated sender: user1@mydomain.dev)`

Clearly the user is using it's legit email address / password to authenticate on the server and then sets the `From` header to the user he wants to impersonate.

I've tested this myself and it works. However, if I change the domain to some domain not on the virtual domains table the email client says the server refused the email.

Is there a way I can make sure `user1@mydomain.dev` is only able to send emails with `from` header matching his email and not someone else on virtual domains table? -- Give an error like it happens when the domain is not listed.

My current `smtpd` restrictions are:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination, reject_unauth_pipelining, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain

smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_invalid_hostname, reject_rbl_client zen.spamhaus.org, reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net, reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org

smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, reject_unknown_address, reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_non_fqdn_sender
```

**Note**: On the server there is plus addressing (ex. `user1+something@ mydomain.dev` will deliver emails to `user1@mydomain.dev`) and also a virtual alias maps. For someone posting a solution to the problem above can you make sure the user is still able to "impersonate" is own emails based on plus-addressing or aliases. I need then to be able to send from `user1+something@mydomain.dev` or `alias-f1@mydomain.dev` (only if they belong to them).

Thank you.

Comment: You might be able to set something up using the [`reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_restrictions) as part of your `smtpd_sender_restrictions`. Haven't tried it, though.

Comment: Well after `reject_authenticated_sender_login_mismatch` I always get `5.7.1 <user1@mydomain.dev>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user user1@mydomain.dev”.` Maybe I've to set `smtpd_sender_login_maps` as well, so it can tell postfix witch users can't send? @tarleb

Comment: But... `smtpd_sender_login_maps` usually contains something like `user1@mydomain.dev user1` establishing a relationship between (authenticated) users and message addresses. Can I just point this to the same thing as `virtual_mailbox_maps` and then maybe change the MySQL query to include alias as well?

Comment: @tarleb I managed to make it with your precious help (again). If you want just replay the question with this answer I've made http://pastebin.com/9dZ0wWgQ and I'll gladly accept it. Without your help I wasn't able to get to that solution. Thank you.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.  If you don't mind, just add a self-answer, I think you now know more in this matter than I do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**With precious help from @tarleb (that pointed me on the right direction) I managed to come up with this solution:**

1. Add `reject_sender_login_mismatch` to the end of the `smtpd_sender_restrictions` section;
2. Since I've `virtual_mailbox_domains` and `virtual_alias_maps` based on MySQL queries, add  `smtpd_sender_login_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender-login-maps.cf`. This is the maps used by postfix to make sure the sender login email and `from` field match;
3. Create `/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_sender-login-maps.cf` with the following content:

   ```
   user = emailserveruser
   password = sdfjn1234ns
   hosts = 127.0.0.1
   dbname = mailstack
   query = SELECT * FROM (SELECT email FROM `virtual_users` WHERE email = '%s' UNION SELECT destination FROM `virtual_alias` WHERE source = '%s' ) a
   ```

**How does it work?**

Postfix will give you the `From` email as `%s` and it excepts to receive as result of a query an address that matches the one used on the SMTP authentication.

In this case we first query the `virtual_users` table and if nothing is returned from there (meaning there's no real user with that email) we query `virtual_alias` in order to get the `destination` address (a real user mailbox) that matches a potential email alias (our `source` field).

If there's no match, the query returns nothing, it means that: 1) there's no such user with that email 2) there's no such alias to any user with that email -- Postfix then gives the mail client a `Sender address rejected: not owned by user` error.